# I want to encrypt my symfony 2 application and make closed source

Tags: symfony, zend-guard

I want my application symfony2 to be encrypted and closed source for developers, i have used zendguard the index page is working but when it call other pages it give me an annotation exception :

> *[Semantical Error] The annotation "@ORM\Table" in class SevenDaysTrade\GestionDeStockBundle\Entity\Produit was never imported.
>   Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?*

Did someone know other solution? or something make my symfony app closed source?

Comment: Show us your code of `SevenDaysTrade\GestionDeStockBundle\Entity\Produit`

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the entity work properly before encoding your project with Zend Guard?
2. Is the following at the top of your entity class?

   ```
   <?php

   namespace SevenDaysTrade\GestionDeStockBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   ```

   Note that you can't just `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` because the annotation is `@ORM\Table`.